# How to create a custom installation package?

Tags: windows, installation

I am a developer and sometime I need to work on new computer, I have to do setup various programming tools, like Visual Studio, gVim, Notepad++, setting up environment variables, etc. etc. Obviously, it takes a lot of time. I would like to do everything at once, by having some kind of automated installer-like package for this. How can I do this? I am working on Windows.

Comment: Cloning your hard disk and stripping the existing Windows license is not an option?

Answer (score 0):

Use the virtual machine). Set all once and you'll have plenty many fine tuned environment for programming).

Answer (score 0):

There's no straight answer to your question. There are many ways to achieve this, I'll just post a few.

One way is to make your own installer which would bundle all the other installers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software#Windows

Another way would be to have a PowerShell script to install all these apps from a network location.

Thirdly, you could use a configuration management tool like [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/puppet) or [Chef](http://www.getchef.com/chef/) to automatically keep a machine and its software in a certain state.